# Video Player (Chewie Controller) is playing all videos which are not in view - Flutter Android

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm using Video Player & Chewie in my app project which is working fine but the issue is that, it is auto playing all the videos at once. However, I want to autoplay the video which is only in view, not all at once, same like instagram. I did check the documentation on pub.dev but unable to find such thing, I might be wrong at some point as I'm not that good in Flutter. Here is the code:

```
// import 'dart:js';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:chewie/chewie.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_rating_bar/flutter_rating_bar.dart';
import 'package:fluttershare/models/user.dart';
import 'package:fluttershare/pages/activity_feed.dart';
import 'package:fluttershare/pages/comments.dart';
import 'package:fluttershare/pages/home.dart';
import 'package:fluttershare/widgets/progress.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

class Post extends StatefulWidget {
  final String postId;
  final String ownerId;
  final String username;
  final String foodname;
  final String placename;
  final String cityname;
  final String statename;
  final String mediaUrl;
  final double rating;
  final dynamic likes;

  Post({
    this.postId,
    this.ownerId,
    this.username,
    this.foodname,
    this.placename,
    this.cityname,
    this.statename,
    this.mediaUrl,
    this.rating,
    this.likes,
  });

  factory Post.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    return Post(
      postId: doc['postId'],
      ownerId: doc['ownerId'],
      username: doc['username'],
      foodname: doc['foodname'],
      placename: doc['placename'],
      cityname: doc['cityname'],
      statename: doc['statename'],
      mediaUrl: doc['mediaUrl'],
      rating: doc['rating'],
      likes: doc['likes'],
    );
  }

  int getLikeCount(likes) {
    if (likes == null) {
      return 0;
    }
    int count = 0;
    likes.values.forEach((val) {
      if (val == true) {
        count += 1;
      }
    });
    return count;
  }

  @override
  _PostState createState() => _PostState(
        postId: this.postId,
        ownerId: this.ownerId,
        username: this.username,
        foodname: this.foodname,
        placename: this.placename,
        cityname: this.cityname,
        statename: this.statename,
        mediaUrl: this.mediaUrl,
        likes: this.likes,
        likeCount: getLikeCount(this.likes),
      );
}

class _PostState extends State<Post> {
  final String currentUserId = currentUser?.id;
  final String postId;
  final String ownerId;
  final String username;
  final String foodname;
  final String placename;
  final String cityname;
  final String statename;
  final String mediaUrl;
  String rating;
  int likeCount;
  Map likes;
  bool isLiked;

  _PostState({
    this.postId,
    this.ownerId,
    this.username,
    this.foodname,
    this.placename,
    this.cityname,
    this.statename,
    this.mediaUrl,
    this.rating,
    this.likes,
    this.likeCount,
  });

  buildPostHeader() {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: usersRef.document(ownerId).get(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return circularProgress();
        }
        User user = User.fromDocument(snapshot.data);
        bool isPostOwner = currentUserId == ownerId;
        return ListTile(
          leading: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundImage: CachedNetworkImageProvider(user.photoUrl),
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
          ),
          title: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => showProfile(context, profileId: user.id),
            child: Text(
              user?.username ?? '',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          trailing: isPostOwner
              ? IconButton(
                  onPressed: () => handleDeletePost(context),
                  icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
                )
              : Text(''),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  handleDeletePost(BuildContext parentContext) {
    return showDialog(
        context: parentContext,
        builder: (context) {
          return SimpleDialog(
            title: Text("Delete This Post?"),
            children: <Widget>[
              SimpleDialogOption(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                  deletePost();
                },
                child: Text(
                  'Delete',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                ),
              ),
              SimpleDialogOption(
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                  child: Text('Cancel')),
            ],
          );
        });
  }

  deletePost() async {
    postsRef
        .document(ownerId)
        .collection('userPosts')
        .document(postId)
        .get()
        .then((doc) {
      if (doc.exists) {
        doc.reference.delete();
      }
    });

    storageRef.child("post_$postId.mp4").delete();

    QuerySnapshot activityFeedSnapshot = await activityFeedRef
        .document(ownerId)
        .collection("feedItems")
        .where('postId', isEqualTo: postId)
        .getDocuments();

    activityFeedSnapshot.documents.forEach((doc) {
      if (doc.exists) {
        doc.reference.delete();
      }
    });

    QuerySnapshot commentsSnapshot = await commentsRef
        .document(postId)
        .collection('comments')
        .getDocuments();

    commentsSnapshot.documents.forEach((doc) {
      if (doc.exists) {
        doc.reference.delete();
      }
    });
  }

  VideoPlayerController _controller;
  Future<void> _initializeVideoPlayerFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(mediaUrl);
    _initializeVideoPlayerFuture = _controller.initialize().then((_) {
      setState(() {});
    });
    _controller.setLooping(true);
    _controller.setVolume(1.0);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  //                                     Post Chewie Display...

  buildPostImage() {
    return FittedBox(
      fit: BoxFit.contain,
      child: mounted
          ? Chewie(
              controller: ChewieController(
                videoPlayerController: _controller,
                aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                autoPlay: true,
                looping: false,
              ),
            )
          : Container(),
    );
  }

  handleLikePost() {
    bool _isLiked = likes[currentUserId] == true;

    if (_isLiked) {
      postsRef
          .document(ownerId)
          .collection('userPosts')
          .document(postId)
          .updateData({'likes.$currentUserId': false});
      removeLikeFromActivityFeed();
      setState(() {
        likeCount -= 1;
        isLiked = false;
        likes[currentUserId] = false;
      });
    } else if (!_isLiked) {
      postsRef
          .document(ownerId)
          .collection('userPosts')
          .document(postId)
          .updateData({'likes.$currentUserId': true});
      addLikeToActivityFeed();
      setState(() {
        likeCount += 1;
        isLiked = true;
        likes[currentUserId] = true;
      });
    }
  }

  addLikeToActivityFeed() {
    bool isNotPostOwner = currentUser != ownerId;
    if (isNotPostOwner) {
      activityFeedRef
          .document(ownerId)
          .collection("feedItems")
          .document(postId)
          .setData({
        "type": "like",
        "username": currentUser.username,
        "userId": currentUser.id,
        "userProfileImg": currentUser.photoUrl,
        "postId": postId,
        "mediaUrl": mediaUrl,
        "timestamp": timestamp,
      });
    }
  }

  removeLikeFromActivityFeed() {
    bool isNotPostOwner = currentUser != ownerId;
    if (isNotPostOwner) {
      activityFeedRef
          .document(ownerId)
          .collection("feedItems")
          .document(postId)
          .get()
          .then((doc) {
        if (doc.exists) {
          doc.reference.delete();
        }
      });
    }
  }

  buildPostFooter(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0, left: 20.0)),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: handleLikePost,
              child: Icon(
                isLiked ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
                size: 28.0,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0)),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => showComments(
                context,
                postId: postId,
                ownerId: ownerId,
                mediaUrl: mediaUrl,
              ),
              child: Icon(
                Icons.supervised_user_circle,
                size: 28.0,
                color: Colors.blueAccent,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 50.0)),
            Icon(Icons.location_on, color: Colors.blueAccent),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 2.0, top: 5.0, right: 10.0),
              child: Text("$cityname " + "$statename",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blueAccent)),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
              child: Text(
                "$likeCount likes",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, top: 10.0, bottom: 5.0),
              child: Text(
                "$foodname ",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0)),
            Icon(
              Icons.restaurant,
              color: Colors.blueAccent,
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.blueAccent,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 2.0),
              child: Text(placename.toUpperCase(),
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    isLiked = (likes[currentUserId] == true);
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        buildPostHeader(),
        buildPostImage(),
        buildPostFooter(context),
        Divider(),
        Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0)),
      ],
    );
  }
}

showComments(BuildContext context,
    {String postId, String ownerId, String mediaUrl}) {
  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
    return Comments(
      postId: postId,
      postOwnerId: ownerId,
      postMediaUrl: mediaUrl,
    );
  }));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy paste run full example code below 
You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/inview_notifier_list 
You can call `VideoWidget` with `inViewState.inView('$index')` 
When not in view, Video will pause

working demo

[image]

code snippet

```
builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
                    final InViewState inViewState =
                        InViewNotifierList.of(context);

                    inViewState.addContext(context: context, id: '$index');

                    return AnimatedBuilder(
                      animation: inViewState,
                      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
                        return VideoWidget(
                            play: inViewState.inView('$index'),
                            url:
                                'http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerJoyrides.mp4');
                      },
                    );
                  },
```

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:inview_notifier_list/inview_notifier_list.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

class VideoWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String url;
  final bool play;

  const VideoWidget({Key key, @required this.url, @required this.play})
      : super(key: key);
  @override
  _VideoWidgetState createState() => _VideoWidgetState();
}

class _VideoWidgetState extends State<VideoWidget> {
  VideoPlayerController _controller;
  Future<void> _initializeVideoPlayerFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(widget.url);
    _initializeVideoPlayerFuture = _controller.initialize().then((_) {
      // Ensure the first frame is shown after the video is initialized, even before the play button has been pressed.
      setState(() {});
    });

    if (widget.play) {
      _controller.play();
      _controller.setLooping(true);
    }
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(VideoWidget oldWidget) {
    if (oldWidget.play != widget.play) {
      if (widget.play) {
        _controller.play();
        _controller.setLooping(true);
      } else {
        _controller.pause();
      }
    }
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _initializeVideoPlayerFuture,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return VideoPlayer(_controller);
        } else {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}

class VideoList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      fit: StackFit.expand,
      children: <Widget>[
        InViewNotifierList(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          initialInViewIds: ['0'],
          isInViewPortCondition:
              (double deltaTop, double deltaBottom, double viewPortDimension) {
            return deltaTop < (0.5 * viewPortDimension) &&
                deltaBottom > (0.5 * viewPortDimension);
          },
          children: List.generate(
            10,
            (index) {
              return Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 300.0,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 50.0),
                child: LayoutBuilder(
                  builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
                    final InViewState inViewState =
                        InViewNotifierList.of(context);

                    inViewState.addContext(context: context, id: '$index');

                    return AnimatedBuilder(
                      animation: inViewState,
                      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
                        return VideoWidget(
                            play: inViewState.inView('$index'),
                            url:
                                'http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerJoyrides.mp4');
                      },
                    );
                  },
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Container(
            height: 1.0,
            color: Colors.redAccent,
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(child: VideoList()),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```